# getPublicUrls() returns an empty array

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

I have a repository of Media objects in my Symfony app that contains a picture. (This picture was uploaded using the Sonata Media Bundle.) Using the following code in my controller ...

```
    $images = $repository->findAll();

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        /* @var $image Media */
        $urls = $image->getPublicUrls();
        $output[] = [
            'name' => $image->getName(),
            'something' => $urls,
        ];
    }
```

... results in an empty array where I had hoped to see at least one public-facing url.

What have I misconfigured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
    $images = $repository->findAll();

    /* @var $imageProvider ImageProvider */
    $imageProvider = $this->get('sonata.media.provider.image');

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        /* @var $image Media */
        $output[] = [
            'name' => $image->getName(),
            'url' => $imageProvider->generatePublicUrl($image, 'reference'), 
        ];
    }
```

This doesn't really answer my original question, but it achieves the goal that I was going for, in that it provides a publicly accessible url for my image.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see in Sonata\MediaBundle\Model\Media no such method getPublicUrls and if I'm right this is your custom method and you have to populate before save media. if I'm right here you can do it in image provider :)